# Trains in Armenia and Iran

Tags: trains, iran, armenia

Are there good train connections from Yerevan, Armenia to Tehran, Iran? What is the price?

Answer (score 11):

There are no direct train connections between Armenia and Iran ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_Republic_of_Iran_Railways#Links_to_Republic_of_Azerbaijan_and_Armenia),[Iranrail.net](http://www.iranrail.net/network.php))

If you can make it to Jolfa or Tabriz, you can take a train from there.